# Rakefile - parameter and directory dependency on task

Tags: ruby, rake, rakefile

I want to cleanly lookup various directory paths using shell commands in a rakefile, assign that value to a variable, and then use that variable to create directories (and use in other tasks).  I've put the `sh` code in a task and made the `directory` calls dependent on the task (using the `file` call after `directory`).  However, I'm not able to use the variable anywhere outside of the task (even with making it global).

```
$my_root = String.new

task :find_path do
    sh %{git rev-parse --show-toplevel} do |pass, res|
      if ! pass
        puts "git rev-parse failed, are you in a git repo? (status = #{res.exitstatus})"
      else
        $my_root = res
      end
    end
end

$MY_DIR        = "#{$my_root}/some/sub/dir"

desc "Create MY_DIR directory"
directory $MY_DIR
file $MY_DIR  => :find_pmc_path
```

I get the following error:

```
mkdir -p /some/sub/dir
rake aborted!
```

When I dig further, the $MY_DIR does not get assigned correctly.  If I place that variable assignment in the task I get an `undefined method 'length' for nil:NilClass` error.

How can I look up the information, assign the variable, and use it in multiple other tasks within the rakefile?

Comment: After experimenting further, I realize that `sh` does not return the std_out result of the command.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a good use case for the `namespace` declaration:

```
namespace :top do
  mydir = 'my_root'
  task :find_path do
    puts mydir
  end

  task :delete do
    puts mydir
  end
end
```

find_task:

```
rake top:find_path
=> my_root
```

delete task:

```
rake top:delete
=>my_root
```

Comment: Are global variables only seen within a namespace (versus the entirety of the rakefile)?  That seems odd...